# Why when calling a method from a anonymous function this is the object but a direct call throws an error

Tags: javascript, closures

With the following:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "john";
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };
}

var me = new Person();
```

Why would a proceeding:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert(me.getName())}, 3000);
```

returns `john` while a proceeding:

```
setTimeout(me.getName(), 3000);
```

create a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getName'
```

Comment: This cannot be your code. I'm assuming your line `setTimeout(me.getName(), 3000);` is not directly proceeding your `var me = new Person();` line as you say. Further, you do mean `setTimeout(me.getName, 3000);` (no parentheses)

Comment: @rgthree "(no parentheses)" -- awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) takes a function as the first argument.

In your code snippet:

setTimeout(function(){alert(me.getName())}, 3000);

You are passing in a function as the first argument which is then evaluated to do the alert.

In the second snippet you're passing in the *result of invoking the function* so this:

setTimeout(me.getName(), 3000);

Becomes this:

setTimeout('john', 3000);

Because of the way `setTimeout` works it will allow you to pass in a string as the first argument that the runtime will attempt to invoke as a function resulting in an error.

Comment: Why is the error message referring to `getName` and not `john`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is the code you used? `setTimeout(me.getName(), 3000)` calls `me.getName` and then passes the result as the first argument of `setTimeout`.

If you meant `setTimeout(me.getName, 3000)` it's because the function isn't bound to `me`, so `setTimeout` executes it in the context of the `window` (where would it get `me` from? You only passed the function itself).

Instead of putting the call inside an anonymous function, you could use bind:

```
setTimeout (me.getName.bind (me), 3000);
```

This isn't available in older browsers, but the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) has a fallback implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question with the correct answer: closures.  When you are wrapping the code in an anonymous function, you create a closure which *captures* the value of the local variable called me.

As James pointed out the part of the question that doesn't work is a little weird.

Comment: It's not totally clear how the `me` variable is captured when inside a closure (as the closure has nothing to do with where me was defined) but when calling the variable from using `me.` outside a closure it isn't available

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly whithout seeing more code, but basically that's what closures do -- they capture all variables accessible lexographically at the point where the closure is created.